# Loops with egen in Stata

Tags: loops, stata

I have a data set which looks as follows:

```
  delta    taubar
   0       1.5
  -0.223   2
   3       6.5
   0.334   2
   11      7
   2.123   1.5
```

`delta` takes different values corresponding to `taubar`. However, I would  like to create a variable which takes the mean of `delta` for each value of `taubar`. That is, if `taubar` holds a value of 2 with a frequency of say 400, and for each of these 400 `delta` is different, I would like to create a variable which is the mean of `delta` for each value of `taubar`.

I have used

```
egen meandelta = mean(delta) if taubar == 2
```

In this case Stata creates a value of say 0.234 which is the mean of the deltas across all 400 2's. This is inefficient; also, there are 600 `taubar`s in the data set, each which may have 500 corresponding `delta`s. 
I would like to end up with each `taubar` from 1.5 to 327 corresponding to the mean of its `delta`s.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but there's no need to loop.

If you want to keep your original data, try:

```
bysort taubar: egen meandelta = mean(delta)
```

You might also consider:

```
collapse (mean) meandelta=delta, by(taubar)
```

but that will destroy your data and replace it with a dataset of means.

Comment: Agreed that it's inefficient to put a single mean in a variable, so as Dimitriy explains put all the means in  a new variable.